# Delete Windows Driver Device Class in Registry

Tags: registry, driver, guid, inf, devcon

I have a .INF with a security descriptor HKR,,Security,,"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)".

I changed this security descriptor to remove admin rights. So that any user can open the application. The descriptor I used is "D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;BU)(A;;GA;;;S-1-1-0)"
I uninstalled the driver in Device Manager and reinstalled the modified .INF file. However, it doesn't work unless I change the device "class" and "ClassGUID" in the INF file.

I think previously installed security descriptor is not deleted even though I deleted the driver from device manager. I also used devcon to delete the driver. But it didn't delete the device class.

Only way I can make it work is to modify "Class" and "ClassGUID" of the existing .INF file.

How can I remove the device class of the previously installed driver in windows?
I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Using SetupAPI, you can also just change the SDS.  This doesn't directly answer your question, but it does solve the problem of not udating the security descriptor.

```
static GUID MY_GUID  = { 0x91A3EB99, 0x5FB7, 0x4CA4, { 0x83, 0xC9, 0x8E, 0x39, 0xC1, 0x39, 0xEF, 0xE8 } };

SetClassSDS(&MY_GUID);
```

If you want, you can also just pass in the GUID you retrieved from SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameEx:

```
SetClassSDS(&cls);
```

This is my function used above (be sure to use the ACL you want):

```
void SetClassSDS(GUID* guid)
{
   wprintf(L"\tGUID: {%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}\n", 
      guid->Data1, guid->Data2, guid->Data3, guid->Data4[0], guid->Data4[1], guid->Data4[2], 
      guid->Data4[3], guid->Data4[4], guid->Data4[5], guid->Data4[6], guid->Data4[7]);

   const int strSize = 256;

   //    This discretionary ACL: 
   //       * Deny access to Built-in Guests
   //       * Deny access to Anonymous Logon
   //       * Allow read/write/execute to Authenticated Users
   //       * Allow full control to Administrators
   WCHAR newStr[strSize] = L"D:(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)";

   PBYTE str = new BYTE[strSize];

   DEVPROPTYPE type;

   DWORD reqSize = 0;

   if (SetupDiGetClassProperty(guid, &DEVPKEY_DeviceClass_SecuritySDS, &type, str, strSize, &reqSize, DICLASSPROP_INSTALLER))
   {
      wprintf(L"\tCurrent SDS: %s\n", str);

      wprintf(L"\tDesired SDS: %s\n", newStr);

      if (SetupDiSetClassProperty(guid, &DEVPKEY_DeviceClass_SecuritySDS, type,
         (BYTE*)newStr, sizeof(newStr), DICLASSPROP_INSTALLER))
      {
         wprintf(L"\n\tSetupDiSetClassProperty succeeded\n\n");
      }
      else
      {
         wprintf(L"\tSetupDiSetClassProperty - Error code: 0x%X\n\n", GetLastError());
      }
   }
   else
   {
      wprintf(L"\tSetupDiGetClassProperty - Error code: 0x%X\n\n", GetLastError());

      if (reqSize > strSize)
      {
         wprintf(L"\tSecurity string too long\n");
      }
   }

   wprintf(L"\n");

   delete [] str;
}
```

You will need the following includes:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <devpkey.h>
#include <devpropdef.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
```

You will need to link to this library:

```
Setupapi.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to finally uninstall the device class using a small C++ program. 
In the following link, at the end of the site, there is a C++ code which you can delete driver completely including the ClassName Associated with the ClassGUID.

https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=168171

I have also copied the same code below as well. I made a small MFC application to perform the uninstallation.

```
    HDEVINFO devs = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA devInfoListDetail;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
    unsigned int DeviceNo = 0;
    GUID cls;
    DWORD numClass = 0;
    TCHAR devID[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
    SP_REMOVEDEVICE_PARAMS rmdParams;
SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameEx ("ClassName", &cls, 1, &numClass,
                             NULL, NULL);
devs = SetupDiGetClassDevsEx (&cls, NULL, NULL,
                       DIGCF_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, NULL);
devInfo.cbSize = sizeof(devInfo);
while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo (devs, DeviceNo++, &devInfo))
{
     devInfoListDetail.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoListDetail);
     if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInfoListDetail (devs, &devInfoListDetail) ||
         CM_Get_Device_ID_Ex(devInfo.DevInst, devID,
                             MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN/* 200 */, 0,
                            devInfoListDetail.RemoteMachineHandle))
    {
         break;
     }
    rmdParams.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
    rmdParams.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_REMOVE;
    rmdParams.Scope = DI_REMOVEDEVICE_GLOBAL;
    rmdParams.HwProfile = 0;
    SetupDiSetClassInstallParams (devs, &devInfo,
                                      &rmdParams.ClassInstallHeader,sizeof 
(rmdParams));
    SetupDiCallClassInstaller (DIF_REMOVE, devs, &devInfo);
}
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(devs);
DEVINST devRoot;
if(CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(&devRoot,NULL,CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL,NULL) != 
CR_SUCCESS) {
        goto final;
}
CM_Reenumerate_DevNode_Ex(devRoot, 0, NULL);
final:
return;
 }
```